# "Inquire" error from reading IBM queue messages from Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure, ibm-mq, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to read messages from a IBM queue with a Azure Logic App with the "MQ" trigger.

Problem is that its not only reading, but making an inquire (ie. reading the depth of the queue etc). and we are not allowing that due to security concerns/settings.

Is it possible to turn this off or configure this, so it does not make any inquire?

Comment: Al object-oriented languages will inquire about an MQ object; it is the nature of the beast. Also, there is no security risk about an application inquiring about the queues that they are using. Now, if you said it was doing it to a queue it was not using then yes, I can see the concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, MQ connector in Logic apps it does enquire about entire queue, it reads till the end of the queue.

[image]

And this is how the connector works, so I would suggest you to use Azure functions or custom integration.

For further refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-mq?tabs=consumption).